Question about divergence free vector fields
Let $Z = (z_1,z_2,\dotsc, z_n)$ be a smooth vector field which is divergence free, i.e., $\operatorname{div}(Z) = 0$. I am trying to prove the following estimate:
$$ \int_{B_1} \langle Z, \Delta Z \rangle dx + \frac12\sum_{i,j}\int_{B_1} (\partial_{x_i}z_j - \partial_{x_j}z_i)^2 dx \geq 0.$$
Here $\Delta Z = (\Delta z_1, \Delta z_2, \dotsc, \Delta z_n)$ is just taking the Laplacian of each component. Is this true in general?
If $Z = \nabla u $ for some $u$ which is harmonic, then the above inequality is an equality. I am trying to see if this is true in general for other divergence free vector fields
